# Use String from Array to LatLng in new activity

Tags: android, arrays, google-maps, listview, latitude-longitude

I can't overcome issue with LatLng which I use to put pin on the map. I use different data (like name, phone number etc) from string-array. I also put there latitude and longitude of the place. So when user clicks on position on listview he gets info about different places. All works fine except sowing the position on the map. 
The coordinates come from String-array in strings:

```
  <string-array name="latitude">
    <item>XX.XXXXXXX</item>
    <item>XX.XXXXXXX</item>
    <item>XX.XXXXXXX</item>
  </string-array>

  <string-array name="longitude">
    <item>XX.XXXXXXX</item>
    <item>XX.XXXXXXX</item>
    <item>XX.XXXXXXX</item>
   </string-array>
```

I pass data like this and all work super

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String[] title = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_string_list);
        final String name = title[position];   
        String[] address = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.address);
            final String addressplace = adres[position];   
         String[] phone = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.phone);
            final String phonenumber = telefon[position];
         String[] lat = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.latitude);
            final String infolatitude = lat[position];
         String[] longi = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.longitude);
                final String infolongitude = longi[position];

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Contact.class);

        intent.putExtra("address", addressplace);
        intent.putExtra("telefon", phonenumber);
        intent.putExtra("lat", infolatitude);
        intent.putExtra("longi", infolongitude);
        startActivity(intent);
```

And in the next activity I try to use Lat+Lng in map to show the pin

public class Contact extends Activity {

```
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private final LatLng LOCATION =new LatLng (latitude,longitude);
private GoogleMap map;

String title;  
String address; 
String phone;
String lat; 
String longi; 


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);

    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOCATION));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION, 15));

    TextView tvTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_text); 
    TextView tvAddress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1_address);
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.textView2_tel);


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

    if (extras != null) {

        tvTitle.setText(extras.getString("title")); 
        tvAdres.setText(extras.getString("address"));
        btn.setText(extras.getString("phone"));
        latitude = Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getStringExtra("lat"));
        longitude = Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getStringExtra("longi"));
        }}
```

The map doesn't show the correct location but opens somewhere near Africa.
I should appreciate your assistance in making this code - showing location - work.

Comment: *somewhere near Africa* coordinates `0,0` perhaps?

Comment: Did you check if `latitude` / `longitude` had correct values after you obtained them in `onCreate()` of `Contact` activity ? Also show your code where you call the map itself

Comment: coordinates ar ok - I checked it by putting it in textview and it was passed corectly. There is a MapFragment in the code already. I guess I just put them in Location in the worng way and therefore need your help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
The problem is that you have intialized the LOCATION variable with the default value of latitude and longitude i.e perhaps (0.0,0.0) default value of double variable.

Do the following changes to get the updated values from intent and then show it on the map   
 if (extras != null) {

            tvTitle.setText(extras.getString("title")); 
            tvAdres.setText(extras.getString("address"));
            btn.setText(extras.getString("phone"));
            latitude = Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getStringExtra("lat"));
            longitude = Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getStringExtra("longi"));
            }}
    private final LatLng LOCATION =new LatLng (latitude,longitude);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOCATION));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION, 15));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had all those elements in wrong position and it made the problem and your answer made it work! Thanks lot Gyanendra Mani